# Verb + object + verb

Tags: licensing

Which one of this two sentences is correct?

- I need you to help me **do** this job
- I need you to help me **to do** this job

Can you also provide me some explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *licensing* matter, which is discussed in a little more detail [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/3231/32). Briefly, the types of construction which you may employ in subordinate clauses are determined by the verb which the clause complements: each verb ***licenses*** (permits) some types of construction and prohibits others.

In your example, the constructions *licensed* by the verb *need* are those with a *marked infinitive* (*to* + *VERB*) :

> I need **to help** you.
>    I need you **to help** me.
>    I need for you **to help** me. ... *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>✲</sup>I need you **help** me.

In contrast, the verb *help* licenses constructions with the *bare infinitive*:

> Help me **do** this job.

At one time, *help* also licensed constructions with the *marked infinitive*, but this use is less common today, and has an old-fashioned ring.

> <sup>?</sup>Help me **to do** this job.

It’s not exactly wrong, and you should not be disturbed if you encounter it; but I recommend that you restrict yourself to constructions with the *unmarked infinitive*.

Note that this is entirely different from constructions in which *to* acts as a preposition rather than an infinitive marker:

> John helped his father **to** his feet. ... *meaning John helped his father rise*
>    John helped us **to** London. ... *meaning John helped us make our way to London*

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable* <sup>?</sup> *marks an utterance as possibly unacceptable*

Answer (score 0):

Some verbs are commonly followed by an object and the base form of another verb. Verbs are let, make, have, help. Examples:

> Please HELP me call people.
>
> Could you HAVE her text me?

Some verbs are commonly followed by an object and an infinitive. Verbs are invite, ask, tell, remind. Examples:

> Could you REMIND them to come early?
>
> I INVITED you to come.