# all you need to do is figure out - if "figure out" is changed to "to figure out", how does the meaning change?

Tags: to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

> Like most programming problems, if you understand the logic behind what you’re trying to accomplish, all you need to do is **figure out** a way of representing that logic with programming code. So let’s think for a moment about the problem we have to solve.

How would the meaning of the sentence change if **figure out** was changed to **to figure out**?

Comment: This can help you: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/is-this-construction-correct-what-it-does-is-to/3231#3231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning between **to-infinitives** and **bare infinitives**. The use of one form or the other is generally determined by the verb controlling the infinitive clause.

Typical examples of a verb requiring the use of a *to-infinitive* are:

> I **want to go** home.
>   I **need to go** home.

Other verbs admit both **to-infinitives** or **bare infinitives**, e.g.:

> I will **help** you **go** home.
>   I will **help** you **to go** home.

Auxiliary and most modal verbs don't admit a *to-infinitive*, e.g.:

> I **did go** home.
>   I **will go** home.
>   I **should go** home.
>   I **needn't say** anything.
>   I **need go** home. *(rare)*

A few modal verbs demand a *to-infinitive*, e.g.:

> I **was unable to go** home.
>   I **ought to go** home.

The lexical verb *need to* and the modal verb *need/needn't* are an interesting case. Note that whereas *need/needn't* doesn't admit a *to-infinitive*, *need to* demands it. As a consequence, it is possible to find both:

> I **need to go** home. *(common)*
>   I **need go** home. *(rare)*

A search in [Google's n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need+go+home%2C+need+to+go+home&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneed%20go%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20to%20go%20home%3B%2Cc0) reveals that the use of *need + bare-infinitive* is rare.

---

The example in this question:

> [...] all you **need to do** is **figure out** a way [...]

is compounded by the use of two verbs, *need* that usually takes a *to-infinitive* and *do* that takes a *bare infinitive*.

Based on the above arguments, one would expect the following uses:

> all you **need** is **to figure out** a way
>   all you **need to do** is **figure out** a way

However, another search in [Google's n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need+is+to%2Cneed+to+do+is%2Cneed+to+do+is+to%2Cneed+is+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneed%20is%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20to%20do%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneed%20to%20do%20is%20to%3B%2Cc0) reveals that the following alternative, although rare, is also possible:

> all you **need to do** is **to figure out** a way

Answer (score 5):

Both forms are correct, and they mean the same thing. The form without the "to" is more common. (I did a search in the COCA corpus. The form without the "to" is six times more common.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using **to** in front of **figure out** would be correct and acceptable, but unnecessary, since **figure out** here is governed by the first **to**. In a sentence without the first **to**, you would have to supply it:

> All you need is **to** figure out...

Since it would be incorrect to say: **All you need is figure out**, we know that **to** is not optional in your sentence - it is required, and present, supplied by the first **to**. However it can be restated with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As Dangph says, both forms mean the say thing. I would say these represent stylistic options. Using "to figure out" gives the sentence a more formal and precise tone to it. However, the beginning of the next sentence "So let's think..." makes reveals that the tone of the paragraph is meant to sound informal.